# Angular 4 - Style Tag remains in HTML after rerouting

Tags: html, css, angular, angular2-template

I have created an angular 4 application. This includes the components: *app.component*, *home.component* and *feature1.component*.

**app.component:**

```
@Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['app/app.component.css'],
      encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent  { }
```

**home.component:**

```
@Component({
      templateUrl: 'app/Components/home.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['app/Components/home.component.css'],
      encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class HomeComponent { }
```

**feature1.component:**

```
@Component({
      templateUrl: 'app/Components/feature1.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['app/Components/feature1.component.css'],
      encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class Feature1Component { }
```

**app.routing:**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'feature1', component: Feature1Component }
];
```

Now I wanted to overwrite some styles in the header of *app.component* when loading the *feature1.component*. This now works with *ViewEncapsulation.None*. However, the style tag now remains in the HTML document when switching back to *home.component* and the styling of the website header remains the same as on the *feature1.component*-page. How can I remove the Style Tag from *feature1.component*?

[image: Illustration of workflow]

Comment: can you give small demo of the problem hard to figure out with words

Comment: If it works with default encapsulation, you could use that with `::ng-deep` in the styles to make the styles working anyway.

Comment: Components should be self contained, and you shouldn't be trying to override styles in one component from another. Instead, make the app component (the parent component), capable of recognizing the child component currently in view, and have it change its own style based on that using *ngClass in the parent component.  You could either have the parent check what child is loaded, or a better pattern would be to have the loaded child emit an event to the parent with the colour, and have the parent style itself based on the colour passed from the child, or a default if no child is loaded.

Comment: Also, setting ViewEncapsulation to none should only be done in very specific cases where you can't style the component content any other way (Bootstrap tabs / accordions etc. fall into this case). Leaving it set to its default prevents exactly the kind of style bleed you're seeing here.

Comment: @Stephen R. Smith Thank you for your constructive help! I will try with your advises.

Answer (score 0):

I have now created a new component called *header.component*. 
Now I load this in *home.component* and *feature1.component*.

**HTML feature1.component:**

```
<div class="small-header">
     <header-content></header-content>
</div>
```

**HTML home.component:**

```
// no wrapper "small-header"
<header-content></header-content>
```

**CSS header.component:**

```
/* Styles to override in small-header */
:host-context(.small-header) header {
     padding: 15px;
     background: #45505b;
}
...
```

Now the header is only changed on the *feature1.component* page and it works as I wanted without affecting the default Encapsulation.